# Custom display suite field

Tags: views, 8, display-suite

## In a custom module I have defined a display suite field like so:

```
namespace Drupal\custom_dsfields\Plugin\DsField;
use Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsField\DsFieldBase;
//Views
/**
 * Plugin that renders the field.
 *
 * @DsField(
 *   id = "total_hours",
 *   title = @Translation("Total hours"),
 *   entity_type = "node",
 *   provider = "custom_dsfields",
 *   
 * )
 */
class MyField extends DsFieldBase
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function build(){

        $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
        $entities = [];
        $hours = [];
        foreach ($node->field_hours as $key => $value) {
            array_push($entities, $value->target_id);
        }
        $entities = entity_load_multiple('user_entities', $entities, $reset = FALSE);
        foreach ($entities as $key => $value) {
            array_push($hours, $value->field_hours->value);
        }
        $hours_sum = array_sum($hours);

        return array(
            '#markup' => '<strong>Total hours for this day ' . $hours_sum . '</strong>'
            // '#theme' => 'item_list',
            // '#items' => $hours_sum
            );
        }
    }
```

In the default display this works perfect. (open to improvements 
But **when I use a view, and display the teaser display with this field in it then the field is not working. Why is this?**

Some things I am questioning...

- Am I loading the node in the correct way as I am not entirely sure what routeMatch() is doing.
- Should I be doing this in a view template (hope not)

Thanks DSE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way to access the node so this will work anywhere.

```
$this->entity();
```

Inside the current class it will load the entity, in this case, the node.

Happy drupaling!